# ReactJS: get <img> src property from ASP.Net Core server

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm new to ASP.Net and Clean Architecture. Here is my problem.

All my uploaded images are stored in Infrastructure Layer inside `Img` folder.

My client is in WebApp Layer.

[image]

How can I get `src` property of `img` tag for my React client to display the `img_0` in `Img` folder?

Comment: did you just try `import imgSrc from '../path/to/img0'`?

Comment: although to use that in development mode wih CRA you'll need img0 in `/public`. Or symlink the directory